# Run NUnit on Mono?

Tags: mono, nunit

Does anyone know if you can run NUnit on Mono? The reason I ask is because on [the download page](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) it says:

> For some releases, we provide a zipped package for use under Mono.

However, the only release that actually has a separate mono release (judging by its label that says "mono:" and then shows the .zip) is the ancient 2.2. NUnit's most recent version is 2.4.8 so I would really rather not use that old of a version.

Can you use the recent version of NUnit on Mono? If not, is there anything I could do to get it to work? What exactly makes something Mono runnable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mono 2.4 will ship with NUnit 2.4.8, and has been in use by the Mono project for their tests for several months, so it should work pretty well.

Mono 2.4 preview: http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/preview/download-preview/

Answer (score 6):

To answer any other "Will x run on mono..." they've produced a tool called the Mono Migation Analyser.

It can be found [here](http://mono-project.com/MoMA) and will show you what methods (if any) mono is missing to run your application.