# Are there common C# tdd frameworks working on Mono?

Tags: c#, tdd, mono

Are there any unit-testing and mocking frameworks for C# that run on Mono ?

Comment: if you use NUnit on C#/.NET you may find an answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613578/nunit-on-mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613578/nunit-on-mono)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono's aim is to provide a complete implementation. If you find a C#/.Net application that doesn't work on Mono (and doesn't fail just because of some p/invoke or something) you might have found a bug in Mono.

In other words: Every native (read: fully managed) C# based framework *should* work on Mono.

Things I'd look at (note: I didn't test them on Mono, but see above):

- [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/)
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Rhino.Mocks some time ago. http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx.

Also a version of NUnit is already embedded in Mono, and has a nice GUI in the MonoDevelop IDE.